# fn is not a function - discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, discord.js

I added this section and when I run the command it says `fn  is not a function`

```js
     if (fn(val, key, this))
                ^
```

```js
bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) 
    {    
       case 'ssremaining':
                // Get our server
                const guild = bot.guilds.cache.find('701549737068855317');

                // Get our stats channels
                const totalUsers = bot.channels.get('701871141219729538');
                const roleUsers = bot.roles.get('715204365601865769');
        break;
    }
})
```

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same! It's two completely different languages.

Comment: sorry, im new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you're not using a function inside `find()`

```js
const guild = bot.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id === '701549737068855317');
```